# Query in an array

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have a model designed like that

```
asset Myasset identified by assetId {
    o String assetId
    o String[] elements
}
```

I would to make a query, but I don't found how to request an element in the array.
I badly tryed the simple way

```
query Q1 {
description: "Example query in an array"
statement:
    SELECT zzz.yyy.xxx.Myasset
      WHERE
         (elements[0] == "Request")
}
```

But it doesn't work

Is there a statement equivalent of the SQL `IN` ? To have something like

```
"Request" IN elements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we do not yet support queries across elements in an array. If you wish to create a Github issue for this, that would be good.

Answer (score 1):

Currently `IN` is not supported by Hyperledger Query Language,

You can do like this: `(elements CONTAINS "Request")`

Already answered here: [#1701](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/1701)